# import DLL compiled in C++ in windows in MOno

Tags: mono, dllimport, smartcard

I have a dll file that has been created and compiled with C++ under Windows and I unfortunately don't have the source code for it.

This dll file is working well with a .NET program compiled with visual studio.

I want to know if this is possible to import this dll file with mono, and execute it under a UNIX environment.

This dll file is sending some Smartcard APDU instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably no. Binaries are platform specific.

You can always try to disassemble it on Windows and try to compile the disassembled code on unix, however I think it's not worth it.

Comment: ...if the license permits you to disassemble it. You may be violating some license agreement if you do this - best to check.